# Concurrent editing with nonce in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, concurrency, mongoose

I am making a multiplayer game using Expressjs, Socket.io, and Mongoose. Players join the game, and it starts when there are enough players to play. I alert all the players in the game at the same time that the game can start, so I'm running into concurrency issues for changing the state of the game to "playing" and initializing the characters. Sometimes the characters will be assigned twice, which messes up gameplay.

I tried to add a nonce as recommended [here](http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2014/03/22/a-pattern-for-handling-concurrent/) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/metadata-and-asset-management/#create-and-edit-content-nodes), but I couldn't get it to work and I didn't really understand it. Does MongoDB treat it as a special value with special properties? Or is the nonce depending on some existing properties of MongoDB?

Here's the relevant parts of the Game model:

```
GameSchema = mongoose.Schema
  nonce:
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    required: true
    default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
  name:
    type: String
    required: true
    unique: true
  state:
    type: String
    enum: ["setup", "unstarted", "playing", "assassinating", "good_won", "bad_won", "discontinued"]
    default: "setup"
    required: true
  characters: [String]
  players: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Player" }]

GameSchema.statics.findByIdAndStart = (id, done) ->
  Game = this

  Game.findById id, (err, game) ->
    return done err, game if err or game.state is "playing"

    changes =
      state: "playing"
      nonce: mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
    Game.update { id: id, nonce: game.nonce }, changes, (err) ->
      return done err if err

      Game.findById(id).populate("players").exec (err, game) ->
        return done err if err

        characterSelection = new CharacterSelection game.characters

        async.eachSeries game.players, ((player, next) ->
          player.character = characterSelection.assignCharacter()
          player.save next
        ), (err) -> done err, game
```

**How do I prevent concurrent editing of my model?**

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about making a property of your model be named "nonce" it is simply a term/convention meaning "used only once" and we require that it is unique each time it is generated.

You define the nonce as an ObjectId in MongoDB so that each time it is generated you should get a unique value.

The key to this working is that when you call update(), you use the existing nonce value of the doc so that your update ensures that no other player or user has updated the doc between the time you issue findById() and call the update method.  If the update was successful your doc will get the newly generated nonce value that you've put in your changes object.

Looking at your code I think it looks correct except you aren't handling the case that the update did not change any records, only the error case. The callback to update ([in Mongoose 3.8.x](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)) takes a second parameter numberAffected that you can use to determine if there were documents affected.

```
Game.update { id: id, nonce: game.nonce }, changes, (err, numberAffected) ->
  return done err if err
  return done "Conflict!" if !numberAffected
```

You need to decide how to handle the Conflict case, in [this example](https://gist.github.com/mpalmerlee/9709085#file-postservice-js), the code retries the call a number of times before it errors out.